# How to use colored cells along with multiple criteria data in formulae

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, colors

I have an issue where I need to use SumIf/SumIfs formula to accomplish the following:
 - Find cells within the spreadsheet filled with different colors which indicates a specific product and test for specific data components e.g C/B/M/A      or C/B/M/F/A or S/Rg within these cells. 
 - Then sum each of the component/color combinations, e.g Green cells containing "M" or "A" or Orange cells containing "F" etc., with a sum-range to determine area coverage of each component/color combination. 
 - Then add all similar components/color combinations over 4 week as a single monthly total for that combination
 - Then multiply the result with another sum-range to arrive at a total monthly usage of each product (component)

Comment: If the cells are colored using conditional formatting, you will need to use the rules by which they are colored in your formula.  If they are not then you will need to use vba.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks Scott, I have tried the vba route but unfortunately it did not solve the issue, as it seem to not recognise the colour id when used in the rest of the code. I have resorted to a marker in the adjacent (hidden)cell  for the interim while searching for a solution that works for me.

Comment: David, I was asking about using colours in SUMIF/SUMIFS formulae. i have a situation that eventhough more than one cell might have the same colour the data might be for different actions. I therefore need to test for a colour then for the action and the sum the different actions/figures. The cells are not coloured using Conditional Formatting. I have tried the vba route which did not work 100%.